# Can you demote SBS 2003 DC with Exchange still working

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003

I'm sitting with a bit of a delema, and I don't want to demote the AD on the SBS 2003 server before I know it is safe.

We are consolidating servers, and I installed a new Windows 2008 R2 Standard Server, and promoted it into the same DC forest. I've transferred the FSMO roles, and now after 21 days the SBS is complaining about another domain in the forest.

Exchange is running on this SBS. I want to demote the DC on the SBS 2003 server, but Exchange must still be operational.

Is it possible for the SBS 2003 server to run as a normal server with Exchange running on it, and use the new DC?

The new DC have all users and roles replicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I used SBS 2003, but I believe if you demote it, you will still be violating the licence (because it's not a DC and doesn't hold the FSMOs), and therefore you will still have the issue of the server trying to shut itself down.

Best recommendation would be to install Exchange server elsewhere and migrate mailboxes and public folders to that before decommissioning the old SBS server. Alternatively, migrate to Office 365/Exchange Online.

There are ways to disable the validation checks which will prevent the server from shutting down, but from a legal point of view, you will still be violating the licence agreement.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that much, that is why I transferred the FSMO roles back to the SBS machine, and it doesn't shut down anymore. SBS is such a waste of money actually